# update config file programmatically during runtime

Tags: java, runtime

I have a config.properties file that i want to update during runtime (for example, if the app receives a certain rest call, it updates the config properties).

Is this doable in java? or we can't change the config file on runtime?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using Java's `Properties` class, you can easily do it like this:

```
final Properties config = new Properties();
```

You can load a config file to your in-memory config like this:

```
final File f = new File("config.properties");
if(!f.exists) {
    f.createNewFile();
}
final InputStream in = new FileInputStream(in);
config.load(in); //loads the config into the Properties object
in.close();
```

And if you wish to save the `Properties` back to a file, you can do:

```
final OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
config.save(out, "Some config comments...");
out.close();
```

You would probably need to wrap this in a `try-catch` block, but that's basically it.

Comment: but how to get the path of the file?

Comment: Do you *know* where your config file should be located?

Comment: it is under resources

Comment: this doesn't update the real file, i mean if we kill the server, the modification will be lost.

Comment: @user2627156 It does. If you always do this after editing the config object it will be written to the file immediately.

Comment: it does not, it doesn't write on the real file but on the resource loaded on the server..

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, i assume you're using the `Properties` API? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

You can use the `store` method specifying an `OutputStream`

Answer (score 0):

logback uses Joran internally, which enabled logback to read configuration files and update them "on the fly" when their content changes. I used this functionality in 2011 and as far as I know Joran still is part of logback.

You could do something like this:

```
ruleMap = new HashMap<Pattern, Action>();

SetProfileParameterAction profile = new SetProfileParameterAction();
ruleMap.put(new Pattern("*/profile"), new AddProfileAction());
ruleMap.put(new Pattern("*/profile/description"), profile );
ruleMap.put(new Pattern("*/profile/link"), profile);

SimpleConfigurator simpleConfigurator = new SimpleConfigurator(ruleMap);

simpleConfigurator.setContext(context);

try {
    simpleConfigurator.doConfigure(cfgFile);
} catch (JoranException e) {
    log.error( "failed ...", e);
    StatusPrinter.print(context);
}
```

Please note: this is just a non-complete cut-down version of my code but if Joran works for you this example will give you a hint in which direction to go ...